# Pull Images from directory - PHP

Tags: php, image, directory

I am trying to pull images simply from my directory /img and load them dynamically into the website into the following fashion.

```
            <img src="plates/photo1.jpg">
```

That's it. It seems so simple but all of the code I have found basically doesn't work.

What I have that I am trying to make work is this:

```
   <?php
   $a=array();
   if ($handle = opendir('plates')) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
   if(preg_match("/\.png$/", $file)) 
        $a[]=$file;
else if(preg_match("/\.jpg$/", $file)) 
        $a[]=$file;
else if(preg_match("/\.jpeg$/", $file)) 
        $a[]=$file;

}
closedir($handle);
   }

 foreach($a as $i){
echo "<img src='".$i."' />";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work."  Is there an error?  What _does_ the code return?  If you debug it, at what point does observed behavior deviate from expected behavior?  What are the relevant runtime values when that happens?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is too vague. Do you have an error? If yes please describe it? Otherwise what happens that you don't expect?

Comment: A regex just to match the file extension is very inefficient. If you insist, however, you should at least combine the three file types.

Comment: It shows nothing. No errors. Shows nothing. There is a picture in the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want your source to show up as `plates/photo1.jpg`, but when you do `echo "<img src='".$i."' />";` you are only writing the file name. Try changing it to this:

```
<?php
$a = array();
$dir = 'plates';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
  while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if (preg_match("/\.png$/", $file)) $a[] = $file;
    elseif (preg_match("/\.jpg$/", $file)) $a[] = $file;
    elseif (preg_match("/\.jpeg$/", $file)) $a[] = $file;
  }
  closedir($handle);
}
foreach ($a as $i) {
  echo "<img src='" . $dir . '/' . $i . "' />";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done very easily using `glob()`.

```
$files = glob("plates/*.{png,jpg,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE);
foreach ($files as $file)
    print "<img src=\"plates/$file\" />";
```

Comment: Works fine, just replace the print line by this :
    `echo '<img src="' . $file . '"';`

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) instead of opendir/closedir. It's much simpler.

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but you this might get you on the right track

```
<?php
foreach (glob("/plates/*") as $filename) {

    $path_parts = pathinfo($filename);

    if($path_parts['extension'] == "png") {
        // do something
    } elseif($path_parts['extension'] == "jpg") {
        // do something else
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: glob is better, but DirectoryIterator is even better again

Comment: I have not heard of that until now. Looks nice.